# converting ANSI to UTF-8 in Java

Tags: javascript, java, json, utf-8, org.json

I have a string in JSON format. There are character like `\u0025` and I need to convert them to the actual character to which they refer.

is there any direct way in Java by which I can convert these character to the actual ones?

something like `myString.convertToUTF-8();`

I am making call to [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and I get the response in JSON format. I wanted to use a [JSON parser](http://www.json.org/java/) or JavaScript parser to parse the JSON and take the values. That's all I need.

I used console of Google Chrome and when I assigned the response to a variable. it gives me an error which tells `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier(…)`.

In JavScript I wanted to use `JSON.parse(jsonString)`. But I cannot assign the value to `jsonString` in fact.

For converting these character in Java I already have tried following lines which does not change the string at all!

```
String responseFromFB = http.sendRequest(url);

byte[] b = responseFromFB.getBytes();
String str= new String(b, "UTF-8");
```

and here is the sendRequest() function which I have!

```
private String httpReq(String URL, String QueryString) throws Exception 
{

    String url = URL;
    String urlParameters = QueryString;

    URL obj = new URL(url);

    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();


    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

Comment: `new String(string, encoding)`, doesn't it?

Comment: Your JSON parser should take care of this. Can you show what code you're using to parse the JSON?

Comment: `\u0025` is an internal representation of a single unicode code point in Java made up of 6 actual characters. If you have that in your string, then you'll need to use a regex or something to replace them with their actual representation, although you obviously never should have it in the first place. Also you can't have a string in anything but UTF-16 in Java anyhow, so the whole question is rather confusing.

Comment: I have edited my question a bit. @Voo: then I would need to identified all posiible characters and try to replace them with the actual ones!! No?!

Comment: @Suo6613 At the time you have `String responseFromFB = http.sendRequest(url);` it's already over and you have a string in UTF-16, the getBytes() part won't do you any good. Since your input is JSON you should be using a JSON parser and not just the low level http APIs and then deal with it yourself. Treat the underlying disease, not the symptoms. That said, no you wouldn't have to handle each separately since the concept is the same in any case.

Comment: @Voo: what do you suggest? You mean instead of making an HTTP request to the graph? Or after fetching the responce from the Graph?

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was to write

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseFromFB);
String decodedResponseFromFB = jsonResponse.toString();
```